# How to generate triangle shape?

Tags: ngspice

I tried to follow docs, and here is my implementation for triangle pulse:

```
V1 0 1 PULSE(-0.75 0.75 0m 8.335m 8.335m 0 16.67m 0)
```

but the result is:

[image]

although the Rise time is `8.335m` at appears as 0, can someone explain what’s the issue?

Comment: Can you explain what kind of triangle pulse you want to generate and why the result isn't working for you?

Comment: A triangle like in here: https://www.electronicspoint.com/forums/resources/simulating-sawtooth-and-triangular-waveforms.58/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't ask why, but probably it NGspice fails simulating with a pulse width of 0.

The following will work:

`V1 0 1 PULSE(-1V 1V 0 {8.335m-0.5n} {8.335m-0.5n} 1n {16.67m+1n} 0)`

**EDIT**
It seems a known issue: https://sourceforge.net/p/ngspice/bugs/355/

> Are you aware of the fact that setting a (pulse)
>    parameter to 0 does not mean that it becomes
>    0.000000... but that SPICE sees this as a don't
>    care and substitutes it with something (what it
>    thinks is) reasonable? I would expect your actual
>    pulse-width becomes 5 or 10% of the period (I didn't
>    consult the source code for the exact number).

Comment: Thanks! that was very useful :)

Comment: I'm using LTspice a lot and was aware of such issues. See e.g. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/237108/ltspice-default-rising-falling-times-of-pulse-edges

Comment: Yea, I can see that, thank you